# I am not able to publish my website using github pages that I made using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I saw multiple tutorials on YouTube for publishing my site on Github but none of them is helping me.
I created a repository on Github, then I uploaded all my files in the repository and enabled the Github Pages for it, But even after doing so, my website is not being published.

Clicking onto the link that Github Pages redirects me to a page where I can only see my repository description and nothing else.

I am attaching some images for you guys to understand better.

[image: All the files uploaded in my repository.]

[image: The page I am being redirected to.]

Comment: What happens when you access your **public** github pages llink?

Comment: Github takes some time to active your website

Comment: Yes I know Github takes some time. But I've been trying it from over a day now and still unable to publish it.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this steps.

Note: You need to provide your username.gihub.io as a repository name.if this matches exacty then it will work.

https://pages.github.com/

Ex. If your username is xyz then your repository name should be xyz.github.io.